# CKeditor no Image preview when displaying upload Tab first

Tags: ckeditor

I use this code to display Upload Tab first when the Image dialog box is opened

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    if ( dialogName == 'image' ) {
        dialogDefinition.onShow = function() {
            this.selectPage( 'Upload' );
        };
    }
});
```

After uploading image to the server it was not displayed in Tab Preview page and I get this javascript error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeStyle' of undefined image.js?t=DBAA:467
contents.elements.children.children.onChange image.js?t=DBAA:467
```